# Passing arrays to scanf function and variables

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, scanf

Why I have to pass array like variables in `scanf("%type",&array[x])` function,not `scanf("%type",array[x])`, I think they are supposed to be pointers " special pointers which can not point to another address".If I'm wrong hope someone can clarify me.

Another thing have two simple codes here. which one is better ?
I'm interested in clean coding, However I'm still beginner.

```
for(_a_i = 0; _a_i < _a_size; _a_i++) {

    int _a_item;
    scanf("%d", &_a_item);
   _a[_a_i] = _a_item;

}
```

Other one

```
for(_a_i = 0; _a_i < _a_size; _a_i++) {

            scanf("%d", &_a[_a_i]);

       }
```

Comment: All your variable names are _horrible_, sorry.

Comment: `scanf` cannot read an array directly, you need to scanf each array member separately. That's how scanf works.

Comment: I did mean with clean coding memory management and performance not variables naming, by the way variables  names from hakerrank site not mine @SouravGhosh

Comment: @YasserMohamed With all due respect, __you__ posted the snippet, so the naming _belongs_ to you. :)

Comment: You are fully right :) @SouravGhosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why I have to pass array like variables in `scanf("%type",&array[x])` function,not `scanf("%type",array[x])`,...?

Although `array` is an *array*.  The *subscript operator* `[]` designates an element of the array `array[x]`.

Suppose `array[x]` is an `int`.    `&array[x]` is then the address of an `int`, a single `int`.

The question then becomes

> Why I have to pass address of an `int` in `scanf("%type",&array[x])` function, not an `int` as in `scanf("%type",array[x])`,...?

`scanf()` needs to know the *address* of the of where to store the input text conversion to `int`.  All  arguments to a functions are received by value.

Assume `array[x] = 42;` before the function call.  Passing the value of an `int`, as in `scanf("%type",array[x])` would not provide `scanf()` information of where to store the conversion.  It would be the same as `scanf("%type", 42)`, which certainly provides no information to store the result in `array[x]`.

---

Concerning "clean coding".  Both code snippets do not check the result of `scanf()` - a significant shortcoming.  Without that check code does not know of scanning success.

```
if (scanf("%d", &_a[_a_i]) != 1) Handle_Error_or_EOF().
```

Depending on error handling, it may be better to get the data first, before destroying the previous value in `_a[_a_i]`

```
int x;
if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1) Handle_Error_or_EOF().
else _a[_a_i] = x;
```

In cases of *style*, best to code per your group's coding standards.

Answer (score 1):

In specific cases<sup>note</sup>, only an expression with type "array" would convert to "pointer to the first element of the array". This does not apply for individual array elements, so you have to use the addressof operator explicitly while scanning values to the individual array members.

That said, regarding the snippets,

- both are error prone as you never checked the returned value of `scanf()` to ensure safety.
- all the identifiers beginning with an underscore are supposed to be reserved, don't try to use them unnecessarily.

  Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.1.3, *Reserved identifiers*

  > - All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
  >     underscore are always reserved for any use.

---

Note:

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1, (*emphasis mine*)

> **Except when** it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [...]